# NXlog will not start - AlienVault Config

Tags: windows, logging, server, nxlog, alienvault

I am trying to configure NXlog to work with AlienVault based on the guide [here](https://www.alienvault.com/documentation/usm-anywhere/deployment-guide/setup/windows-events-nxlog-ce.htm?Highlight=nxlog)

I installed the custom config file from AlienVault and modified the destination IP only. When I did this I could not get the NXlog service to start - Then I reinstalled the default config but I still cannot get it to open.

I edited the file in notepad which I thing should be safe, however I have read [here](https://nxlog.co/question/2147/nxlog-service-wont-start-when-config-changed) that it is possibly the UTF-8 BOM - I am not sure how to check if there is one but I do not believe there is because I only used notepad.

The first line in the config file looks like so:

`define ROOT C:\Program Files (x86)\nxlog`

The NXlog Log file with the errors is only displaying this error:

`nxlog failed to start: Invalid keyword: define at C:\Program Files (x86)\nxlog\conf\nxlog.conf:1`

Not very helpful - Seems to be choking on the very first word - Anyone seen this before???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As B0ti mentioned, my problem was caused by the BOM - I couldn't figure out how to fix this on windows so I downloaded the file into a Linux environment and fixed it there. To do so follow these steps -

First I verified there was a BOM in place with the `file` command:

ex: `file filename.txt`   -This will print information about the file - if there is a BOM you will see that.

Next I followed the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file) for removing the BOM:

Basically just do this in the Linux box - `sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' < orig.txt > new.txt`

Then I transferred the new file back to the Windows box and all was right with the world!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's caused by the UTF-8 BOM in your config file. I suggest using and checking with an editor that can handle this. In HEX mode you can confirm whether the file has a BOM or not.

The NXLog EE v4.0 can cope with the BOM properly BTW.